# 4Hz sinewave above ground, I want to make it an AC sinewave

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc

I have a circuit that will output a squarewave from about 100 Volts up to 8000 Volts. It was designed to output an 8000 volt squarewave and does, but I changed the input drive from a square wave to a sinewave and it has the resulting 100 Volts up to 8000 Volt DC sinewave. I want to make the output AC and would like it to operate from 4 Hz to 50Hz. Is this as simple as putting in a blocking cap?
The circuit consists of a 12kV DC PS, a 6MΩ resistor then a 6BK4 tube the is pulsed on and off. The load is a 12MΩ resistor. So tube open, I have a 6MΩ and 12MΩ resistive divider with 8kV out, when the tube conducts, it drops 12kV across the 6MΩ resistor and I have zero* volts on the 12MΩ resistor load. *(tube is not a short so I have about 100 volts across it.)
If a blocking cap will work, what size do I need with a 12MΩ load?
Attached is a simplified schematic.[image]

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about this question, for safety reasons.  How aware are you of maintaining safety around such a circuit, when you don't know how to select an appropriate capacitor?

Comment: The 6BK4 was designed more for voltage regulation than active amplification. But I gather you've got an AC input that is small enough that after a gain of circa 2000 it is still relatively 'ac' in nature at the output but riding on some DC (of course.) Assuming the distortion is not too bad for your use, then a blocking cap into your load might work. Your frequency can be quite low. This might push you towards an HV cap nearer 100 nF. Have you found [such a beast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IqFj.png) and tried it? (See [here](https://www.ga.com/capacitors/very-high-voltage-capacitors).)

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this is a redo of a previous answer due to not understanding the non-standard schematic representation of the circuit.*

The corner frequency for a simple RC high-pass filter is:
$$ f_c = {1 \over 2 \pi R C} $$

The capacitance should be 5 to 10 times larger than the capacitance  calculated at the lowest frequency to keep the response reasonably flat above the lowest frequency of interest.

$$ C = {1 \over 2 \pi f_c R} = {1 \over 2 \pi \cdot 4 \cdot 12M} = 3.3 \; nF  $$
If you make the capacitor 10x larger, then 33 nF.

The resistance was chosen at 12 Mohm since I don't want to spend time figuring out the impedance of the tube plate. This gives a conservative capacitor value.

Here's a LTspice simulation of the circuit. See if this come close to the actual circuit. The upper trace is an AC analysis showing that the corner frequency is 3.2 Hz, C1 = 3.3 nF, at 2V grid bias.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain this well, I already have a sinewave output, the problem is, it is DC, it does not go negative, it just rides about 100V above ground. 8kV sinewave that rides on top of 100VDC. Thanks, Mike